# Signature not removed from keyserver

Tags: encryption, certificate, gnupg, digital-signature

I noticed that an on uid of my GPG certificate is two times signed with my key. I thought that doesn't make much sense and cleaned the key (`gpg --edit-key` and then `clean`). Then i send the key to the keyserver (keys.gnupg.net) and then did `gpg --refresh-keys`. The signature was downloaded again. Why is this? Later i looked in the web interface of the server and the signature is still on my key. How can i remove this? Is this even recommended?

The key is [F1787BA](http://keys.gnupg.net/pks/lookup?search=0xF1787BA9&op=vindex). The second sign is on my key since i changed the primary uid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove signatures or UIDs from keys on keyservers. 
You can just revoke them. But they are then still visible as revoked signatures.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be a good idea to revoke one of the signatures or should i just leave them both on the key?